# Receive Wikimedia commons media filePath from file name

Tags: mediawiki, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I trying to build an analytics web ui for the media request data, from the [wikimedia REST API](https://wikimedia.org/api/rest_v1/)

To get media request data, I need to pass filePath in wikimedia commons. For example:
For this [sphinx image](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Sphinx_Metropolitan.jpg) I need to pass the following `filePath`: /wikipedia/commons/9/96/Sphinx_Metropolitan.jpg

Currently I need to do it manually (in the image page, I need to copy the image URL from the embed dialog), is there a way to get the `filePath` programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

I found this api, that provides the wanted information:
https://magnus-toolserver.toolforge.org/commonsapi.php